# Variable changed during game only take effect on next game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Scenario**

I am working on a game where a variable numStamps, starts out at 2,this variable is also set as a public int and I can see it in my inspector and it's in a script called Weather

```
public int numStamps;
```

Now you may think "where is numStamps" being declared as having a value of 2? in the inspector? 
But what I actually have is a gameObject reference in another script named GameMode and I drag the "weather script" into the inspector of that GameMode script.

What this allows is it gives me access to the `numStamps` variable.
The purpose of this is because I have an emum where I modify that `z` variable based on the difficulty that is selected.
See below

```
using DigitalRuby.WeatherMaker;
using MoreMountains.Tools;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class GameMode : MonoBehaviour {
        public GameObject mainCamera;
        public GameObject fallingObjects;
        public GameObject WeatherMaker;
        public GameObject stormHerald; 
        public enum GameDifficulty
    {
        Test,
        Easy,
        Medium,
        Hard
    }
    [Information("Selece Game Mode", MoreMountains.Tools.InformationAttribute.InformationType.Info, false)]
    /// Set Variables based on selected mode


     // public motionDirections motionState = motionDirections.Vertical;
        public GameDifficulty Mode = GameDifficulty.Easy;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        switch (Mode)
        {
            case GameDifficulty.Test:

                stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = 2;

                break;
            case GameDifficulty.Easy:                 

                stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = 2;

                break;
            case GameDifficulty.Medium:

                stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = 2;

                break;
            case GameDifficulty.Hard:

                stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = 3;

                break;
        }
    }


    public void reduceStamp()
    {

      stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps - 1;


    }
    public void extendStamp()
    {

        stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps = stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps + 1 ;


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The problem that I am experimenting is, with my extendStamp method, the method is being called in the code, and the update method is also showing me that the numStamp value is increasing. HOWEVER, in the inspector that does not hold true and situations that should occur when that variable is for example 5, does not occur. Strangely, if `numStamps` is supposed to be 7, this value is only shown on the inspector when I restart the game.

The same goes for the game difficulty, changing the difficulty only changes the values if I start it a second time.

So to me it seems I am updating this value incorrectly, which is weird because I change values in the inspector all the time in my game but I just cant seem to get this instant to work correctly.

Would appreciate some assistance or guidance in this

Regards

**Weather**

```
void Update () {
    timeBetweenStorms -= Time.deltaTime;

    if ( numStamps>0 && isStormyNow == false)
    {
        if (timeBetweenStorms <= 0.0f)
        {

            // timerEnded();

            //  var chanceOfSpawningKremlin = 0.75f;
            float rValue;
            rValue = Random.value;
            Debug.Log(rValue + "% Chance of Storm");
            if (rValue < chanceEvent)
            {
                timeBetweenStorms = timeBetweenIfStorms;
                StartCoroutine(TemporarilyActivateStormWarning(ActivateFor));


            }else
            {

                timeBetweenStorms = timeBetweenIfNoStorms;
            }


        } 

    }


}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the context a bit.. You are setting the `stormHerald` object in Unity's Inspector. Is the `stormHerald` object being set to a reference of a **scene** object, or is it being set to a reference of a **prefab**?

Comment: @vinicius.ras ok let me try to answer best I can, the stormHerald is an object with the script Weather attached. And in the GameMode gameObject i dragged the scene object (stormHerald) not the prefab

Comment: What do you mean by the variable change only takes effect in the next game?  The variable does get incremented at some point?

Comment: What does this `Weather` component do? How is it using the value you set? If it is e.g. only used in `Start` or `Awake` than it won't have any effect changing it afterwards. Pleaase show us the code for `Weather` or at least the necessary parts. Also note that you can use `stormHerald.GetComponent<Weather>().numStamps+=1;` to reduce the amount of code a bit and in general you should do `GetComponent<Weather>()` only once in the beginning and rather reuse this reference since it is kind of expensive

Comment: @slaphshot33324 The value of the variable, does not get incremented at least in the inspector, nor in my game because if I have a condition that occurs when it gets to 5, that code never fires however, if I am logging it out in an update it gets incremented.

Comment: @derHugo I have added the the relevant weather code, it's in the update, not start or awake

Comment: I don't see `numStamps` used anywhere except this line `if ( numStamps>0 && ...)` where the exact value doesn't matter at all as soon it is greater than `0` ...?

Comment: My game will have the ability to increase and decrease this value as well as others, so being able to modify them during playtime is imperative. For now I am working on increasing it when i call my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what is wrong here.

What is probably happening is that you are setting the `stormHerald` variable in Unity Inspector to a **prefab** instead of a **scene object**.

- **Prefabs** are objects that you create in your project folder, they are templates to create objects in your scenes, and they appear in the **"Project"** tab of Unity Editor.
- **Scene objects** on the other hand appear on the **"Hierarchy"** tab of your Unity Editor.

You have set the `stormHerald` variable to a **reference to a prefab** instead of setting it to a **reference to a scene object**. I have illustrated that in the image below: you are taking the blue arrow path, while you should be taking the red arrow path. This means that whenever you change `numStamps` variable, you are setting the variable in the **prefab**, not in the **scene object**. So the scene is not updated, while the prefab is (and changes to the prefab only take place the next time you play the scene again).

[image]

Confirming that is very simple: run your game, do the action you gotta do to change the `numStamps` variable inside the game, and then click on the object that should be modified in the scene. The Inspector will show it has **not** been modified. Then, while still running the game, go to the **Project** tab and search for the **prefab** of the `stormHerald` object and click it. You will see in the Inspector that the value of the `numStamps` variable has changed in the prefab.

Solution to your problem: set the `stormHerald` variable to point to your **scene object**, and not to your **prefab**.